# Is it bad to pass a parent component (i.e. "this") completely to a child component as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a complicated Parent class that fetches data from a server and contains a whole bunch of complicated logic. I now want to render this data in multiple ways. Is there anything wrong with just passing the whole Parent object as a prop to a Child? As follows:

```js
export class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            some_text = "Hello World"
            many many state things that may be set by fetch
            };

        this.some_method1 = this.some_method1.bind(this);
        ...
        this.some_method100 = this.some_method100.bind(this);
        }

    render(){
        if (this.props.renderas === "child1"){
            return <Child1 parent={this} />
            }
        else {
            return <Child2 parent={this} />
            }
        }
    }

export class Child1 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.parent.state.some_text}</div>
        }
    }

export class Child2 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.parent.state.some_other_thing}</div>
        }
    }
```

At first glance this seems like a great idea to me because I can easily render the data in Parent in multiple ways, and I don't have to write a lot of `prop={this.state.value}` lines. I tested it and it seems to work fine.

But I am suspicious because I have not found this solution anywhere online, and it feels like I'm not following the intended logic of React. Is there some reason this is considered a bad pattern, performance- or design-wise? Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

EDIT: I have just learned about the existence of React Redux which is basically what I was after. All the data from the server and the methods to interact with it can be implemented in it, and then instead of a Parent component, I can just make the Childs use the store. That kind of solves everything, except for the fact that I now have to reimplement everything in React Redux...

Comment: You are right to be suspicious.  The premise of React is dynamic changes and using props to communicate specific properties of those changes.  As you have it, your children are just mirrors of the parent component, which doesn't really reflect any use cases I've seen.

Comment: I am a React beginner so I'm probably doing this all wrong. Maybe let me rephrase the question: How do I render the data stored in Parent in different stateless components, without writing a ton of `prop={this.some_method}` lines? And without re-mounting Parent? (The calls to the server are slow so I'd like minimize the amount of necessary calls)

Comment: In addition to messing with React's updating cycle, it kind of violates the [_Law of Demeter_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) where your child component knows too much of its parent's internals.

Comment: Also, if this parent component has all the fetching for the whole app in hundreds of method, it definitely is doing too much and it should be separated in different container components that are defined and used closer to where they're needed.

Comment: It basically gets a bunch of data from a server (which is slow, so I don't want to do it any more than necessary), and then has a bunch of put/update/delete functions to interact with the server. It's about 20 methods overall, all of which I would like to have access to when rendering in some way. Coming from python I've never heard of the law of Demeter :) I realize my question probably is too much of a general architecture question, and is not going to be answered here.

Comment: I have just learned about the existence of React Redux which is basically what I was after. All the data from the server and the methods can be implemented in it, and then instead of a Parent component I just make the Childs use the store. That kind of solves it, except for the fact that I now have to reimplement everything in React Redux...

Comment: You're really onto something great! Keep going with that, there's a lot of examples available. I personally use [redux-actions](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-actions), [redux-thunk-actions](https://github.com/machadogj/redux-thunk-actions) with the [thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and it's easy to debug with its time travelling [devtools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension). Some may prefer Saga or Obervables with RxJS, it really depends on your goal and preferences.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bad practice for some reasons: it is not intuitive, it certainly is a code smell (meaning that, although it works, it probably hides some architectural flaw) and it could cause issues with reference loops between parent and child.

You can accomplish something similar if you're able to use [ES6 Spread](https://dev.to/vuevixens/understanding-the-spread-operator-in-javascript-485j) operator, like below:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      some_text = "Hello World"
    };
  }

  render(){
    if (this.props.renderas === "child1"){
      return <Child1 {...this.state} />
    } else {
      return <Child2 {...this.state} />
    }
  }
}

export class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div>{this.props.some_text}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: That will only pass the state to the Child though, and I need a ton of methods from the Parent as well. Is it also possible to send all methods to the Child?

Comment: Can you isolate those other methods into some separate object or helper class? It's just because it feels weird to pass the whole react component, when all you want is a couple of methods (ok, maybe not a couple, but you get the point)

Comment: The most complicated methods are basically the ones that fetch data from the server and put into the state of the parent. I suppose I could move those to another class the only does fetching, and then pass only that class as another prop. But I feel like at that point passing just `parent={this}` achieves the same thing with less code, right?

Comment: @ComboCosmo if you want to call methods on a parent, just pass down callbacks to the child. `<Child onChildAction={this.fetchSomeData} />`

Comment: @Emile Bergeron Yes that I understand, but I want to pass like 20 methods of the parent class to the child (basically get/put/delete functions for multiple resources). Is there a way to avoid writing 20 lines of `prop={this.some_method}`?

Comment: @ComboCosmo as this point, it has nothing to do with React and relates mostly to how to design and architecture a frontend application, which is way too broad to answer on Stack Overflow with way too little information given in your question.

Answer (score 0):

React allows only one-way bindings, data cannot flow in the opposite way (as would happen with two-way bindings, for example), and this has some key advantages:

- it’s less error-prone, as you have more control over your data
- it’s easier to debug, as you know what is coming from where
- it’s more efficient, as the library already knows what the boundaries
  are of each part of the system

Comment: Everything is still one-way bound though right? Basically I'm just passing `parent={this}` instead of `prop1={this.state.value1}`, `prop2={this.someMethod2}`, etc. The Child will only call Parent methods that are bound to Parent, and is otherwise stateless. Note I don't want to defend the code shown in the question, it smells for sure, but I don't see a problem with one-way or two-way bindings.

Comment: It's only the best practice of using React, not syntax.